# React Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've `ResetPassword` component which renders `Timer` component, below are their code -

ResendPassword.js

```
class ResetPassword extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            resendActive: false
        };
    }

    endHandler(){
        this.setState({
            resendActive: true
        })
    }        

    render(){
        return (
            <Timer sec={5} counter={this.state.counter} end={this.endHandler.bind(this)}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Timer.js

```
const Timer = (props) => {
    const [sec, setSec] = useState(props.sec);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSec(props.sec);
        const intr = setInterval(() => {
            setSec((s) => {
                if(s > 0)
                    return --s;
                props.end(); // Line: causing warning
                clearInterval(intr);
                return s;
            });
        }, 1000)
    
        return () => {
            clearInterval(intr);
        }
    }, [props.counter])

    return (
        <span>{sec > 60 ? `${Math.floor(sec/60)}:${sec - Math.floor(sec/60)}`: `${sec}`} sec</span>
    )
}
```

In Above code I'm using timer in ResetPassword and I want a function call when timer ends so I'm passing endHandler as end in Timer component but calling that function giving - Warning: `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render')`, can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Why do you need to store the props in local component state? This is a react anti-pattern. Why not just use `setTimeout`? Its use-case is more like you describe and it's much easier to manage in react hooks.

Comment: @DrewReese Timer component renders secs and it decreases by 1 for every second and it takes no of seconds it will run from parent, so I've to set secs got from parent in state then decrement it in each setInterval call to rerender decremented second

Comment: Timer is like a countdown 10, 9 ,8... till 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`setSec` is a state update function and you use the functional state update variant. This update function callback is necessarily required to be a pure function, i.e. with zero side-effects. The invocation of `props.end()` is a side-effect.

## Solution

Split out the side-effect invocation of `props.end` into its own effect hook so that it is independent of the state updater function.

```
const Timer = (props) => {
  const [sec, setSec] = useState(props.sec);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSec(props.sec);
    const intr = setInterval(() => {
      setSec((s) => {
        if (s > 0) return --s;
        clearInterval(intr);
        return s;
      });
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intr);
    };
  }, [props.counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sec);
    if (sec <= 0) props.end(); // <-- move invoking `end` to own effect
  }, [sec]);

  return (
    <span>
      {sec > 60
        ? `${Math.floor(sec / 60)}:${sec - Math.floor(sec / 60)}`
        : `${sec}`}{" "}
      sec
    </span>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-warning-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition-such-as-within issue]

## Suggestion

Create a `useInterval` hook

```
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(savedCallback.current, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
};
```

Update `Timer` to use interval hook

```
const Timer = ({ end, sec: secProp}) => {
  const [sec, setSec] = useState(secProp);

  // Only decrement sec if sec !== 0
  useInterval(() => setSec((s) => s - (s ? 1 : 0)), 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    !sec && end(); // sec === 0, end!
  }, [sec, end]);

  return (
    <span>
      {sec > 60
        ? `${Math.floor(sec / 60)}:${sec - Math.floor(sec / 60)}`
        : `${sec}`}{" "}
      sec
    </span>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-warning-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition-such-as-within]

Comment: Yes, this one works, but I didn't get why my one is giving warning

Comment: @AbhaySehgal You're absolutely correct, I just did one of my biggest SO pet peeves, provided an answer but neglected to address the OP issue. For your original code I was able to trace the issue back to the state update function, it can't have side-effects. Moving the side-effect into its own effect hook seems to resolve the warning. I've updated my answer.